# How to alternate between hidden=YES and hidden=NO on a button click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the hidden property set to YES on two UIViews in viewDidLoad. On a button click, they will be set to NO, therefore they will be shown. How do I make these properties switch between yes/no on every button click?

Comment: give code demo..

Comment: `-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender{[self toggleViewVisibility];} -(void) toggleViewVisibility{[self.firstView setHidden:!self.firstView.isHidden];`}`?

Comment: Do you mean something like `view.hidden = !view.hidden` ?

Comment: @Larme, good answer but please don't post whole lines of code in comments. It's pretty much unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two views are, view1 and view2, you would set up the button to hook to an action such as the following:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    view1.hidden = !view1.hidden;
    view2.hidden = !view2.hidden;
}
```

The `!` is the logical `NOT` operator. So it will take the current value for `hidden` (whether it is `true` or `false`) and convert it to the opposite value - so, `true` if it was `false`, or `false`, if it was `true`.

Comment: can you give more details please? I don't understand why this works

Comment: @konyv12 I've added an explanation to the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It should be like this:**

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  drawingView.hidden = !drawingView.isHidden;
}
```

Comment: You missed the logical not operator `!`. It should be `drawingView.hidden = !drawingView.isHidden` as stated by @Fahim.

Comment: oh sorry, now corrected. but if you know all these basic things.. why are asking.